According to the Bible, is science a subset of wisdom?
Judging from the story of the wisest man that has ever lived, wisdom in the Bible seems to imply knowledge that leads a human being to make the right choice morally(right choice between good and evil, right and wrong). Solomon was asked to choose between riches and wisdom, he chose the later. We saw how this wisdom was applied by Solomon in deciding the case of two women who were disputing over a baby. Since science is a type of knowledge, can it be considered part of this wisdom which leads a man to make the right choice and how?

I think of it like in D&D, Solomen asked for wisdom, not knowledge. He didn't ask for secrets, he asked for wisdom. They are different things. :) Solomon was not very bright, considering all the sin he did despite all the wisdom. xD

@Wyrsa, how is scientific wisdom different from the wisdom God gives ?

science isn't about wisdom, it is about facts and best guesses using those facts. It is not wisdom, it is knowledge. Wisdom granted by God is not "knowledge of worldly issues" it is something else. A comment is not sufficient for this... read some wisdom of solomon. :)

The modern concept of science is obviously not spoken of directly in scripture; that would be anachronistic. As for the passage in question…
1 King 3:9-13

So give your servant a discerning heart to govern your people and to distinguish between right and wrong. For who is able to govern this great people of yours?”
10 The Lord was pleased that Solomon had asked for this. 11 So God said to him, “Since you have asked for this and not for long life or wealth for yourself, nor have asked for the death of your enemies but for discernment in administering justice, 12 I will do what you have asked. I will give you a wise and discerning heart, so that there will never have been anyone like you, nor will there ever be.

We see above that what Solomon asked for, and what he was granted, was a discerning heart for administering justice and especially for the purpose of leading Israel. He wasn’t granted all wisdom / knowledge, though of course there is both wisdom and knowledge to be had beyond the administrative role of a king.
He is bolstered as wiser than anyone else, and of course is credited with putting forth numerous proverbs and songs. Surely he understood the various fields of study of his day greater than anyone; but the purpose of that wisdom was to lead Israel - not to advance the various fields of study.
1 Kings 4:29-34

God gave Solomon wisdom and very great insight, and a breadth of understanding as measureless as the sand on the seashore. 30 Solomon’s wisdom was greater than the wisdom of all the people of the East, and greater than all the wisdom of Egypt. 31 He was wiser than anyone else, including Ethan the Ezrahite—wiser than Heman, Kalkol and Darda, the sons of Mahol. And his fame spread to all the surrounding nations. 32 He spoke three thousand proverbs and his songs numbered a thousand and five. 33 He spoke about plant life, from the cedar of Lebanon to the hyssop that grows out of walls. He also spoke about animals and birds, reptiles and fish. 34 From all nations people came to listen to Solomon’s wisdom, sent by all the kings of the world, who had heard of his wisdom.

Is there wisdom to be had in science? Certainly! Does scripture suggest that Solomon was granted modern scientific knowledge? No.

Define true wisdom? Is there a difference between earthly and spiritual wisdom?

I never said anything of “true wisdom.” The only place that appears in scripture is in Job 11:6, and it isn’t necessarily significant as it is one of job’s friends calling him to repent- because “he MUST have done some terrible sin.”  But if I had to  define it I’d point to what Christ asserted: “wisdom is proved right by her deeds.” (Matthew 11:19)

and what is wisdom to you brother RPW?

wisdom is knowledge of good from evil, righteousness is choosing the good and shunning the evil.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Id just consult the dictionary myself: “the ability to use your knowledge and experience to make good decisions and judgments” (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wisdom); ie, discernment

Looks like the dictionary just proved my interpretation right.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany the definition does not limit itself to moral decisions
